# {get;set;} for arrayList in c# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

Is there any solution to use set and get for arraylist ?
I want to put all of my arraylists in one class but then i need them to fill a bidimensional array to use them. (1 list=1 column)

I want to put this

```
ArrayList listanume = new ArrayList();
```

In this :

```
class Beneficiar
{}
```

And use it to fill an bidimensional array like

```
listanume -> a[i,0]
```

I really don't know how to say it right, but this is the idea...

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea for various reasons. Why use an `ArrayList` at all nowadays? Why put them all in one class? What does this data actually represent and what are you trying to achieve with this data structure? What has populating a 2D array got to do with property getters and setters?

Comment: It's a form for accounts and i choose arrays to can add anytime +1. And i need a 2D array because i think it's more easy to search by name, sold or any criteria

Comment: This has [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  written all over it. Instead of asking about your obviously wrong solution, try asking about the problem you need solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that

```
 class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        Account a1 = new Account { Name = "Peter", Password = "lalala", Mail = "mail@yahoo.com", TotalSold = 100M };
        accounts.Add(a1);
    }
}
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSold { get; set; }
}
```

To access any account by some field you can do this

```
string searchNameString = "Peter";
            var foundAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == searchNameString);
            if (foundAccount != null)
            {
                //Code which uses found account
            }
            //Here you will get all accounts with total sold > 1000. You can then iterate over them with for or foreach
            var foundAccountsByTotalSold = accounts.Where(x => x.TotalSold > 1000);
```